# Alternative way to store an auth token in an Angular app

Tags: angular

I am currently implementing an angular application where I am getting an Authentication token from backend. After login I am storing that token in local storage of the browser. Is there any other way to store the Auth token. I am trying avoid local storage or session storage or cookie.

Please suggest if there is any solution. Also, I am getting an refresh token after a certain point of time of login(approx 20 mint).

Comment: Does this help? https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limited options. You need a storage which does not get destroyed after a full page reload. So localstorage or session storage is totally fine to store a token because they normally expire at some point. Cookies would also be an option.

Another alternative I know about would be the index db of the Browser:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db

This is a lightweight database available in all modern Browsers.

Comment: Between Local storage, Session Storage, and cookie which one is the most secure way?

Comment: Cookies seem to be the most secured way. When you create them with httpOnly flag, they are not accessable trough Javascript. Read here for more information: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage